# multiply constant with vector in breeze

Tags: scala-breeze

I am new to breeze. Please help with this formula

I have a Vector called data, a constant called alpha, and another Vector called delay. I want to generate an output Vector adjData.

The elemental operation is

```
adjData_i = (1 - alpha * delay_i)Data_i
```

how to express this using vector operation in Breeze?

Answer (score 2):

```
val adjData = (1.0 - delay * alpha) :* data
```

`*` is for scalar or matrix multiplication (not elementwise), while `:*` is elementwise multiplication, as described in the [Breeze Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet). Otherwise, it mirrors your formula closely.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation for this answer? Thanks!

Comment: Not quite. Remember, delay is a Vector, not a constant. (1.0 - delay * alpha) does not work because of that. Another word, 1.0 is also a Vector of 1.0's.

Comment: What. I'm pretty sure I'm right. Did you even try it:

scala> import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.linalg._

scala> val delay = DenseVector.rand(5)
delay: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(0.9776512215294542, 0.520453583016343, 0.0707914240024825, 0.2683433214302806, 0.7361769748712919)

scala> val data = DenseVector.rand(5)
data: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(0.7326643036788687, 0.9681615533879682, 0.13045469055706738, 0.41302213717901903, 0.0793376135032593)

scala> (1.0 - delay * 0.5) :* data
res0: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] =  ...

Comment: Again, delay is a Vector. you are still treating it like a scalar.

Comment: I literally wrote Breeze. I know how it works. He wants to do elementwise multiplication of two vectors, after scaling and a single operation. My code literally produces the same answer yours does, except it doesn't use nearly as many allocations.

Answer (score -1):

I think this does the job

```
(DenseVector.ones[Double](n) - DenseVector.fill(n){alpha} :* delay) :* data
```

Comment: no. you can't multiply two vectors using `*`, only `:*`. that's the whole point.

Comment: An answer solely consisting of code with no or little explanation makes it difficult to understand for future visitors which mistakes were made originally or which approach should be taken and why your answer is viable. Please add explanations to your code.

Comment: to dlwh, I omitted one : in the first *. I have added it in since. The key is the entire term must be presented as Vectors, thus, the DenseVector.ones[Double](n)  and DenseVector.ones[Double](n) parts.

Comment: here is more explanation of the breeze lib. (DenseVector.ones[Double](n) creates a vector of n dimension, whose elements are all 1. DenseVector.fill(n){alpha} creates another vector, whose elements are all alpha. DenseVector.fill(n){alpha} :* delay is an element wise vector multiplication. Hope its clear now.